# resource file naming convention for user control in .net

Tags: asp.net, globalization

Please advice the naming convention for making resource file for a user control.

For ex lets say my user control name is `Footer.ascx`

then what should be the name of its .resx file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Winforms application, when you build UserControl or new Form and switch Localizable property to true, new .resx file will be generated with name exactly the same as visual control. That is for Form1, .resx file will be named Form1.resx, for UserControl1 it would be named UserControl1.resx.
Obviously if you want to follow that pattern your Footer control should have resource file named Footer.resx.

Answer (score 0):

In DotNetNuke, if the control's named "Control1.ascx", then the resource file is "Control1.resx".